# Cloth parameters database, library or add-on

Tags: cloth-simulation

I would like to be able to simulate as realistically as posible different cloth materials.

I searched for a library or a database that contains the physics parameters of several cloths without success. I only could find materials and textures, without cloth sim parameters.

Any idea if something like this exist? I'm aware of the presets existing built-in in blender, but would be great if a more extensive list exist.